# The URL "http://localhost/magento/" is not accessible. Unable to read response, or response is empty Magento Installtion Error

Tags: magento, installation

The URL "http://localhost/magento/" is not accessible.
Unable to read response, or response is empty
When install new magento in localhost.

Comment: Skip Base URL Validation Before the Next Step 
Checked  above checkbox to solve it.

Comment: Thanks, I didn't recognize the option too +1

Comment: @AnkitParmar: Please post an answer as actual answer.

Answer (score 9):

As Ankit Parmar said, you can check

```
Skip Base URL Validation Before
```

...but you might encounter problems later on. This message appears probably because your domain is not public or not reachable. If you skip Base Url Validation, you will be able to finish the installation but you might get the strange problem of being able to log in but not to access the admin section (get redirected to the login page without any error message even if you see you're logged in by looking at the URL).

Rather than installing Magento under localhost, you should add a fake domain name in your host file and set up a vhost accordingly. you may then re-install Magento by accessing the fake domain name in your browser. You may setup the domain name in the core_config_data table if not done.

More over here: https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/39752/how-do-i-fix-my-base-urls-so-i-can-access-my-magento-site