# Blank frontend at magento

Tags: php, magento, caching, frontend, backend

From last couple of days frontend of magento (localhost) is showing blank,
I tried all the solutions, they are:

1. Clear cache.
2. Renamed the file local.xml.sample to local.xml.
3. Uncommented the comment ini_set('display_errors', 1); in index.php.
4. Turned on developer mode.
5. Disabled and removed custom modules

The backend is working fine but the front is totally blank.
But none of the above worked, any solutions please.

[image: Here is the image]

Comment: did you recently done any chnages, revert back and try....

Comment: yes i did , infact i even used my old backup , but still not working

Comment: was it working in old backup  ? if you are sure, it was working in old backup than dont you think its server issue ?

Comment: yes it was working in old backup, even I think this is server issue but I have no idea what to do with it, if it is with server, can you help please

Comment: try contacting hosting team once....

Comment: It is on localhost, Xampp server

Comment: sorry, i forgotten.....  post here : http://magento.stackexchange.com/ you may get solution soon.....

Comment: is it showing blank page or 404?

Comment: @Shrikant No it is just blank , I have also attached screenshot

Comment: @RichTea Also checked error logs, there are no errors from the time this problem has started

Comment: thank u @PhpBeginner

Comment: In the screenshot the frontend run but a `Block.php` or `template.phtml` make an error and return void

Comment: should check in network panel to catch http error like 404, 403, 500, etc

Comment: @Nolwennig i am not getting your point will you please elaborate

Comment: Do you get the log in or nothing at all? A long time ago I made a change to my htaccess file and got the same symptoms after I logged in (the log in page was fine), when I'd then get a blank page. However, I found if I refreshed the page the dashboard appeared. As everything else worked fine, I never investigated any further.

Comment: @raw_hitt Open http://127.0.0.1/rohit/jetly2 in browser. Open inspector. Go to network panel. Refresh page and look at Status columns.

Comment: @raw_hitt Go to Magento back-office. `System > Configuration > Advanced section > Developers > Debug (expand tab)` and Set the `Template Path Hints` to Yes.

Comment: You may have added a die somewhere?

Comment: I hav got the solution , it was happening because of the layout.xml file which was comming from one of the custom module.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you modified your *base_url* fields in the **core_config_data** table?

I suggest you set your local website using a fake domain name rather than using 127.0.0.1/site/xyz. you can do this by configuring a vhost in Apache (don't forget to modify your hosts file).

Then, since your admin is working, set the Secure and Unsecure urls under System / General / Web to the domain you have created (or change the values manually in the core_config_data table). Drop the var/cache folder and try to display the homepage.

Details over here: 
https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/39752/how-do-i-fix-my-base-urls-so-i-can-access-my-magento-site

[The URL "http://localhost/magento/" is not accessible. Unable to read response, or response is empty Magento Installtion Error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28623675/the-url-http-localhost-magento-is-not-accessible-unable-to-read-response/34232494#34232494)